# PHP Code Notice: Undefined variable: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\myfiles\login.php on line 51 you must enter your password?

Tags: php

The question I am asking has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21366281/php-login-system-error-on-line-51) but was asked pretty badly and resulted in the problem not being resolved. What the guy that asked that question is experiencing is exactly what I am experiencing, I assume he is following the same [YouTube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hAkKC8DKN9A) as me. Anyway here is all of the PHP / HTML code I have written to far:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<?php
$form = "<form action='./login.php' method='post'>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Username:</td>
<td><input type='text' name='user' /></td>
</tr>

<td>Password:</td>
<td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
</tr>

<td></td>
<td><input type='submit' name='loginbtn'  value='Login'/></td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>";

if ($_POST ['loginbtn']){
$user = $_POST['user'];
$user = $_POST['password'];


if ($user){ 
if ($password){ 
echo "$user - $password <hr /> $form";
}
else
echo "you must enter your password $form";

}
else
echo "you must enter your username $form";

}
else
echo $form;

?>
```

I've tried adding a variable to `if ($user){` and `if ($password){` but that did nothing. Anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: This code is quite unreadable....

Comment: except for being a messy code, what error are you getting and what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Horrible horrible tutorial.

Comment: Sidenote: Don't store passwords in plain text. And I fear the rest of your code (SQL) is open to [SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/) - You "are" using a DB right? Oh, still storing in `.txt`? ***Lovely***

Comment: And change `$user = $_POST['password'];` to `$password = $_POST['password'];` if you still want to make this work.

Comment: Yea... I tried watching it and it made my brain _melt_ @PeeHaa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$user = $_POST['password'];
```

$password is not properly defined, and you are using it in the `if` below

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$user = $_POST['password'];
```

This... you are assigning both user and password to the same variable ($user). That is why you have undefined variable password.

Also use `htmlentities` to prevent code injection:

```
$user = htmlentities($_POST['user']);
$password = htmlentities($_POST['password']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, that doesn't look like a very good tutorial. For one thing, I see that you create loginID and password fields on the page, but at what point is a user `submit` received? And where is the code for those values to be passed to PHP, evaluated, and returned?

I suggest these other tutorials instead:

[phpAcademy - Register and Login - OOP version](https://phpacademy.org/videos/oop-loginregister-system)
[phpAcademy - Register and Login - Procedural version](https://phpacademy.org/videos/register-login-old)

[theNewBoston - Project Lisa (adv)](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=51)

From your code, I think you will be most comfortable with the procedural tutorial from phpAcademy, but you should really learn the OOP one.

---

Other comments:

(removed b/c cornelb beat me to the punch -- see his answer.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the tutorial links. They look ten times better than the tutorial I'm following.